# virtualbox-5.2 installation not working

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from the CLI as it is the server edition. I have followed the instructions from:

https://websiteforstudents.com/virtualbox-5-2-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-headless/

However, I get the following error about packages having unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.2 : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
                : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
                : Depends: libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
                : Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                : Recommends: pdf-viewer
E: Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

That manual is for 16.04.

I suggest installing VirtualBox-6.0 from [VirtualBox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Current build is here:
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/virtualbox-6.0_6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb

If you specifically want the 5.2 version, there is an Ubuntu 18.04 build here

https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.26/virtualbox-5.2_5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb

Install it this way

```
wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.26/virtualbox-5.2_5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this makes sense. I am trying to install cuckoo a malware analysis tool which only supports up to 5.2 according to its documentation. Is there a specific way in which I would install the link you provide using a CLI?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: The updated method also gives me errors for multiple other dependencies such as libgl1, libqt5core5a, libqt5gui5 and many more

Comment: It's probably because you tried a wrong one. Run `sudo apt purge 'virtualbox.*'` and try again.

Comment: And the last command should fix the dependencies.

Comment: @BenRichi_ did you add the ppa as instructed in the link in your question? If you did, you should remove that.